# .htaccess not redirecting from old url to new url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

i have developed a website using codeigniter. Previously the site had a long URL structure so i have made them shorter in the new website.

Although i used the redirect directive in htaccess it gives me a 404 error. I have removed all the old controllers and functions.

below is a few lines from htaccess (there are many urls redirecting to new ones)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www urls to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

#RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /payments/charity_and_donations/paid http://www.mysite.com/charity
Redirect 301 /outwards/office_furniture/damaged http://www.mysite.com/office_assets
Redirect 301 /funding/business_and_person/inward http://www.mysite.com/funds
```

can someone tell me why it is not redirecting from the old to the new and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your redirecting happen **before** you route URIs to `/index.php`. Also, since `Redirect` is part of mod_alias and your other redirect/routing rule is mod_rewrite, the URI is being processed twice when it's not supposed to. You should just use mod_rewrite and add the rules to the beginning:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^payments/charity_and_donations/paid http://www.mysite.com/charity [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^outwards/office_furniture/damaged http://www.mysite.com/office_assets [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^funding/business_and_person/inward http://www.mysite.com/funds [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, this works perfectly for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```